# Get all dates in date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im creating a query that gets data based on 1 day currently. I would like it to get data for all dates in a date range so just after ideas and basic structure for how best to go about this.

example query

```
Select date
from table
where date between 01/01/2014 and 05/01/2014
```

Ideally id like the results returns as follows

> 01/01/2014
>
> 02/01/2014
>
> 03/01/2014
>
> 04/01/2014
>
> 05/01/2014

Comment: Do you just want to generate through SQL all dates in a date range?

Comment: What language are you calling this SQL from? It'd be better/easier/cleaner to just do it within the language you're working in (and we can help with that).

Comment: @ahjohnston25 it's tagged `sql-server`.

Comment: @Siyual Yes, though I think the person would be better served learning how to do this the right way, instead of using a way that encourages maintaining a table of dates. If the user tells me what language they're using, I will encourage them to make a new post with the proper tags.

Comment: Hi I am using sql as I want to create a stored procedure to execute in an ssrs so will have 2 input parameters for startdate and end date and want to create a data set to them display on the report. I have the query for 1 day just wanted some suggestions for multiple days, maybe a cursor for example?

Comment: thanks @Siyual that looks to be what I was after, I already have a cte in the query I have so might see if I can work this into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that you wanted a stored procedure for this, so this should work for you:

```
Create Procedure spGenerateDateRange(@FromDate Date, @ToDate Date)
As Begin

    ;With Date (Date) As
    (
        Select  @FromDate Union All
        Select  DateAdd(Day, 1, Date)
        From    Date
        Where   Date < @ToDate
    )
    Select  Date
    From    Date
    Option  (MaxRecursion 0)

End
```

Comment: Be careful here. You are using a triangular join. The performance of this could really ugly if those two dates are far apart. It would be far better from a performance perspective to use a tally table.

Comment: @SeanLange Generating and outputting all 730,486 dates in SSMS from 1000-01-01 to 3000-01-01 took all of 9 seconds.  Inserting them directly into a temp table without outputting the results takes only 2 seconds.  I don't think performance is going to be an issue.

Comment: I disagree. If you do this with a tally table the results are almost instant.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you could do this with a tally table instead of a triangular join.

```
create Procedure GenerateDateRange(@FromDate Date, @ToDate Date)
As
    WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    E6(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E4 a, E2 b),
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E6
    )

    select DATEADD(day, t.N - 1, @FromDate) as MyDate
    from cteTally t
    where N <= DATEDIFF(day, @FromDate, @ToDate) + 1

go
```

Now let's compare the performance of this versus the triangular join method that was chosen as the answer.

```
declare @FromDate date = '1000-01-01', @ToDate date = '3000-01-01'

exec spGenerateDateRange @FromDate, @ToDate
exec GenerateDateRange @FromDate, @ToDate
```

Comment: thanks for suggesting a different way of doing this, ive not heard of tally tables in sql before so I will have a look at this

Comment: Here is an excellent about the topic. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/ It will totally change your mind in how you think about data.

Comment: Thanks, ive just had quick google, would these sort of tables be good for storing multiple answeres in a tickbox for example? I used a cte to start with but came accros issue with amount variables I could pass in from an ssrs report. This mainly happened as I wanted to include an "All" option, ive just seen example where you can use these tables to split strings so this sounds like good solution then to me for another job im working on. Will take a look at your article now as that may answer my own question

Comment: Yes the tally table is kind of like the "swiss army knife" of t-sql. It can be used to replace loops and all sorts of other things with a fast, set-based solution.

Comment: Thanks I hadn't heard of these before so I will def be researching these more

Answer (score 1):

May be this works for you

```
DECLARE @DateFrom date, @DateTo date;
    SET @DateFrom='20140801';
    SET @DateTo='20140805';

    WITH DateRange(date)
    AS
    ( 
    SELECT @DateFrom 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DateAdd(day,1,D.date) FROM DateRange D WHERE D.date < @DateTo
    )
    SELECT date FROM DateRange
```